# how to generate mpd file using edash packager?

Tags: video-streaming, media-player, mpeg-dash

How to generate mpd manifest files using [edash-packager](https://github.com/google/edash-packager/).?

Answer (score 0):

The [Readme.md](https://github.com/google/edash-packager/blob/master/README.md) of the gitlab repo is quite comprehensive and gives you a step by step tutorial. What exactly are your issues with edash?

Alternatively you can try out [x264+MP4Box](http://www.dash-player.com/blog/2014/11/mpeg-dash-content-generation-using-mp4box-and-x264/) or the [bitcodin](http://www.bitcodin.com/blog/2015/02/create-mpeg-dash-hls-content-for-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) service.